# In what state is my code, if I get conflict while applying stash?

Tags: git, github

[image]

I get the following logs on doing a `git stash apply`

I am confused whether, the applied stashed changes had merged ?

Or, the operation has been aborted ?

Does GIT do a half merge.. then abort  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In what state is my code, if I get conflict while applying stash?

From Git's point of view, your code now has changes which are not added to the index. This is no different than if you just edit your code. You can do `git diff` to see what these changes are.

> I am confused whether, the applied stashed changes had merged ?

Your applied stashed changes will appear in your local files with markings indicating where the conflicts occurred. This is the same as when you `git merge` and there are conflicts. The annotated parts of your code contain markings like the following:

- `<<<<<<< HEAD` - indicates the contents of your current branch
- `=======` - indicates the end of the contents of your current branch and is followed by the contents from your stash
- `>>>>>>> new_branch_to_merge_later` - indicates the end of the merge conflict

You need to find these annotations and edit them according to what you want.

> I am confused whether, the applied stashed changes had merged ?
>
> Or, the operation has been aborted ?
>
> Does GIT do a half merge.. then abort ?

No, the applied changes were not merged cleanly because there are conflicts. The operation was aborted so that you can clean up the code to be as you want it. This is a common occurrence, especially when doing `git merge`. I suggest you do some research about merge conflicts.

Comment: When you say 'not merged cleanly' , is that a partial merge, or it means a full merge rollback?

Comment: @AdityaRewari It means that there are conflicts when git attempts to merge. Your local files will be changed with both conflicting versions annotated as I describe in this answer. It is neither a "partial merge" nor a "full merge rollback". You have to edit the conflicts manually. In the case of `git stash apply`, it means that there are changes to your local files. If you were doing `git merge` instead, the merge is aborted and no new commit is created. The annotated changes exist and you have to commit them after you have resolved the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You should have clean state before applying stash. That means you should commit changes or revert before merging them. It is not merged or half-merged.

Comment: Even with a clean state (i.e. no local changes), it is possible to get merge conflicts when applying a stash. The current branch might have changes to the same lines of code that the stash changes.